# unable to scroll in top div

Tags: html, css

Unable to scroll when cursor is over the blue block at the top, any ideas of where I'm going wrong?

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cr8uj/1/)**

**HTML**

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="block">
        block
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        content
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.block {
    background: blue;
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}
.content {
    background: red;
    margin-top: 300px;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
}
.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
  }
```

**JS**

```javascript
$(".wrapper").scrollTop(300);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used css `position: Fixed;`, so class `block` will not move from its position and scrollbar will not work on `mousehover` event

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="block">
        block
        </div>

    <div class="content">
        content
    </div>

 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.block {
    background: blue;
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
.content {
    background: red;
    margin-top: 300px;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
}
.wrapper {
    background: #ccc none repeat scroll 0 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
  }
```

**JS**

```
$( ".wrapper" ).scrollTop( 300 );
```

here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cr8uj/2/)

Comment: I need the block to be fixed, is there any other way round it?

Answer (score 0):

As you have the position to be fixed for the class block it will prevent the scrollbar from working. So change the position for class block.

Answer (score 0):

Removed the wrapper div and add the "body" to the javascript

Update
http://jsfiddle.net/cr8uj/7/

**JS**

```
$( "body" ).scrollTop( 300 );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
please do not use fixed property on .block class

body {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
.block {
background: blue;
height: 300px;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
}
.content {
background: red;
margin-top: 300px;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 100;
position: absolute;
}
.wrapper {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
overflow: auto;
}
```